# Ошибка «Call to undefined relationship» в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Недавно начал изучать Laravel и решил его использовать для своего учебного проекта в колледже - АИС для составления расписания занятий.

Я создал метод в контроллере:

```php
public function show(Request $request){
    if (($request->get('group') == null) || ($request->get('date') == null)){
        return view("timetable.show", ['groups' => Group::all()]);
    }
    else {
        $timetable = new Timetable();
        $dayTimetable = $timetable
            ->with('schedules')
            ->with('subjects')
            ->with('teachers')
            ->with('classesTypes')
            ->with('classrooms')
            ->whereGroup($request->get('group'))
            ->where('date', '=', $request->get('date'))
            ->get();
        return view('timetable.show', ['timetable' => $dayTimetable]);
    }
}
```

В модели создал соответствующие отношения:

```php
class Timetable extends Model
{
    public function schedules(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Schedule::class, 'classes_number');
    }

    public function subjects(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class, 'subject');
    }

    public function teachers(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'teacher');
    }

    public function classesTypes(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ClassesType::class, 'classes_type');
    }

    public function classrooms(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class, 'classroom');
    }
}
```

При вызове метода из контроллера возникает ошибка: `Call to undefined relationship [schedules] on model [App\Models\Timetable].`

Вот миграции для данных таблиц (сгенерированы автоматически):
schedules:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->integer('classes_number')->comment('Номер пары');
        $table->time('start_time')->comment('Время начала');
        $table->time('end_time')->comment('Время окончания');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('schedules');
}
```

timetables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('timetables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->date('date')->comment('Дата');
        $table->integer('classes_number')->index('classes_number')->comment('Номер пары');
        $table->integer('group')->index('group')->comment('Группа');
        $table->integer('subject')->index('subject')->comment('Дисциплина');
        $table->integer('classes_type')->index('classes_type')->comment('Вид занятия (пары)');
        $table->integer('classroom')->index('classroom')->comment('Аудитория');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('teacher')->nullable()->index('timetables_teachers_id_fk');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('timetables');
}
```

Внешние ключи для timetables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('timetables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign(['classes_number'], 'timetables_ibfk_2')->references(['id'])->on('schedules');
        $table->foreign(['classroom'], 'timetables_ibfk_4')->references(['id'])->on('classroom_types');
        $table->foreign(['teacher'], 'timetables_teachers_id_fk')->references(['id'])->on('teachers');
        $table->foreign(['subject'], 'timetables_ibfk_1')->references(['id'])->on('subjects');
        $table->foreign(['group'], 'timetables_ibfk_3')->references(['id'])->on('groups');
        $table->foreign(['classes_type'], 'timetables_ibfk_5')->references(['id'])->on('classes_types');
    });
}
```

Если убрать `->with('schedules')`, то всё работает. Попробовал имя функции скопировать, чтобы исключить неправильное написание, но не помогло. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У with массив передавать можно, вместо тысячи вызовов... Содержание метода show заставляет задуматься о правильности реализации/подхода. Попробуйте переименовать и с другим именем попробовать, если не поможет значит смотреть надо работает это связь или нет

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, не знал, что можно передавать массив :) А что именно предлагаете переименовать? Если метод `schedules()`, то пробовал - не помогло.

Comment: Там не только массив, можно конкретные поля указывать чтобы всё не тянуть, можно колбек функцией условия добавлять для выборки и т.п. Отдельно значит смотрите работает эта связь вообще или нет

Comment: Как это сделать :) В phpMyAdmin проверил, что эта связь существует.

Comment: @InDevX отдельно в этом контроллере попробовал выполнить with с этой связью. Та же ошибка.

Comment: насчет связи belongsTo - уверены? без with посмотрите, хоть просто `$tt = Timetable::all(); dd($tt-> schedules)`

Comment: Про belongsTo почти уверен, но пробовал и другое. А без with посмотреть не очень понял как. У меня нет в Timetable поля schedules, там связь по полю classes_number. Я функцию пробовал и так называть, не помогает.

Comment: опишите какими именно полями связаны, почти уверен что связи не верно прописаны. Как посмотреть я пример кинул выше

Comment: Поле classes_number в Timetable связано с id в Schedule (много к одному).

Comment: Исходя из логики, Timetable может иметь только 1 расписание, значит и связь должна быть hasOne

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло...

Comment: Тогда миграции давайте для обеих таблиц

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Непонятно. По миграциям, связям всё так же добавил и работает. Попробуйте почистить кеш и пр.